# What is cross-type's definition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am study PostgreSQL's source code, cross-type is mentioned many times, but there are seemly not clear definition about it, and google's result also tell me cross-type only exists in PostgreSQL. Any one tell me what is cross-type, especially give me some examples? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is some info here that may be useful http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html

Comment: @CraigRinger , #@KonstantinV.Salikhov thank you very much! you reminded me to read them more attentively again, and got it.